# Python ZeroMQ : connecting two different clients together in a ROUTER and a REP configuration

Tags: networking, zeromq, distributed-system

I have a configuration with the following server/clients :

- One server with two bound sockets, a **`REP`** and a **`ROUTER`**
- A client (we will call it a ***worker***) that stays connected to the `ROUTER` socket
- Another (real) client that connects on the `REP` socket.

I want the server to be able to tell the real client to connect (directly or somehow through the server) to a websocket, opened on the ***worker*** client. But it seems, I cannot retrieve the worker's IP-address from a ZeroMQ socket.

How could I achieve this, without some dirty IP-address retrieve hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How could I achieve this, without some dirty IP-address retrieve hacks?

The best would be to use an explicitly communicated IP-address dialogue / handshaking between the <kbd>**`server`**</kbd> and the <kbd>***`worker`***</kbd> which would take place upon their setup / initialisation, in which the ***worker*** adviced these configuration details to server, upon having been asked to provide a such answer.

Given that, the "*new*"-real-client **`.connect()`**-s it's **`REQ`** onto the server's **`REP`**, and asks the server about where to go next, the server thus can answer this and the "new"-real-client will get received this way a legitimate IP-address:port# and any additionally needed details for any additional TCP/IP-L3 service establishment and use.

That simple :o) [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system)

---

<sub>**Design-side Epilogue:**

Because there are some further, design-side implications, hardwired inside of each type of the ZeroMQ sockets' Access-Point, it might be found more appropriate to serve a separate **`REP`**-AccessPoint on the server side, so as not to subordinate each "*new*"-real-client to become dependent upon a presence of events outside of the domains of control of both the server and such "new"-real-client, but to rather allow both such **`REQ/REP`**-endpoints to enjoy the independence of anything but their temporally (semi-)private details (re-)negotiation(s).</sub>

Comment: Okay, so the worker should know his own public IP adress. That is not a problem in my situation. I am guessing that if the server had to do this job, ZeroMQ would not be the proper solution?
btw : I love your writing style, it is juste exquisite and inspiring.

Comment: **Appreciate your kind compliment, @aze -** so as to keep your view balanced, let me tell you that many people literaly hate this very style :o) **On topic:** - ZeroMQ is absolutely a great set of tools, not easily paralleled, except nanomsg and similarly carefully crafted low-latency / high-performance infrastructure tools for [tag:distributed-system]